# How to avoid Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, calabash, pageobjects

While I'm executing the scenarios suddenly I got the error message as follows:

```
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:803:in `initialize'
```

How do I resolve and overcome from this issue.

Comment that I used to execute is:

- cucumber features/ APP_PATH=...../.../../test.app DEVICE=ipad SDK_VERSION=6.1

Comment: Make sure you actually have a process listening to port you're trying to connect to (the error means you haven't).

Comment: Are you running into this issue still? was it on an environment like jenkins? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24448375/1565615

Answer (score 4):

i faced the same error, and it was because elasticsearch service not running. simply did:
`sudo service elasticsearch start`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to launch the app on a simulator?  Ensure that the simulator is running and the -cal app has been launched.  This should open that port for communication.