# calabash-ios unexpected ECONNREFUSED error after touch

Tags: cucumber, calabash-ios

xcode install
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

calabash version

```
➜  calabash.framework git:(master) ✗ Resources/version
0.9.169
```

Calabash Server Version

```
{
                        "outcome" => "SUCCESS",
                         "app_id" => "<removed>",
               "simulator_device" => "iPhone",
                        "version" => "0.9.169",
                       "app_name" => "iPhone-cal",
    "iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad" => false,
                          "4inch" => true,
                            "git" => {
        "remote_origin" => "git@github.com:calabash/calabash-ios-server.git",
               "branch" => "master",
             "revision" => "ca62f6e"
},
                    "app_version" => "1.0",
                "    iOS_version" => "7.1",
                         "system" => "x86_64",
                      "simulator" => "iPhone Simulator 463.9.41, iPhone OS 7.1 (iPhone Retina (4-inch)/11D167)"
}
```

Target Etc.

```
export DEBUG=1 DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone Retina (4-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1'
```

The problem is that when I run cucumber I get the following random failures (which will also cause the build to fail and have caused me to remove functional testing from our CI/CD stack).

```
0.9.169/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:161
    Then I touch "Nationstar Bank"                                 # calabash-cucumber-0.9.169/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:15
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    Then I wait to see "Choose Date"                               # calabash-cucumber-0.9.169/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:161
    enter code here
```

Other info:

```
Apple OS : 10.9.3
```

Comment: You mention random failures.  Does it only fail at this step randomly, or does it fail in other places?  You also mention CI/CD - does this kind of failure only happen during CI/CD?  At first blush, this looks like your app is crashing when the "Nationstar Bank" button is touched.  Subsequent calls to the calabash server are resulting in Errno::ECONNREFUSED:.

Comment: Yes they are are random.  Sometimes that test will pass on subsequent runs of the cucumber script.  This happens on my local machine as well.  The app is not crashing, since that yields a different error from Calabash, specifically a JSON parse error.

Comment: Thanks for the FO.  An app crash can result in a ECONNREFUSED _or_ a JSON parse error.  Is it the case that _only this_ Step fails randomly, or do other Steps fail in the same way? Can you post more of your Scenario - what is happening before this Step?  Are you seeing this on physical devices as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing similar issues seeing lots of "ECONNREFUSED". When run on a local machine it worked fine but on Jenkins CI it failed.

It was caused by the build directory (APP_BUNDLE_PATH) not being removed when the job was started.

This is because "Wipe out repository and force clone" does not remove files that are not present in git i.e "./Build".